# my application is working fine with JDK7 but with JDK8, it's giving stackoverflowerror

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat7, tomcat8

I don't know why it is not working with JDK 8 using Tomcat 8 version and spring 4.2. I had tried in all ways I can,but unable to find the solution.
Is there any changes I may forgot to specify in the configuration, I am using log4j and slf4j for the logging.

This is the stack trace:

> 2016-Jan-20 10:49:45,143 [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (localhost-startStop-1) []
>   WARN  Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyApp' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/app-3.0.1-dev.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-dao.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'DaoTarget$child#67d4bbb3' of type [DaoImpl] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DaoTarget$child#67d4bbb3': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Try moving to a new version of spring.

Comment: I had this problem with Spring before, try turning it into a maven project and then update the pom.xml to a recent configuration which works for Spring.

Comment: I am using spring 4.1.4 version.

Comment: It's a maven project only